# How to get rid of spam on the rating page

Tags: facebook, spam, facebook-apps

Spammers like "5000 free FB credits" post every 30 minutes on the rating page. How to get rid of those posts. Marking "as spam" does not make any sense because no reaction from FB on those marking. Is any FB API call that "filter" such spam?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it's not possible as far as I know.

It's a real problem, too, because it pretty much makes the 'reviews' useless with all the spam in there.  Facebook should really either come up with a solution for the spam (such as remove comments on the reviews) or get rid of reviews.